# Colorize terminal output by pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal, command-line-interface

I have an app which generates some output:

```
$ my-app
[metadata] - [21:06:51 DBG] Some message 111 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware>
[metadata] - [21:06:52 DBG] Some message 222 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics>
[metadata] - [21:06:52 ERR] Some message 223 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher>
[metadata] - [21:06:54 DBG] Some message 333 <s:PocApi.MyApp.Foo>
```

I remove the `[metadata] -` part of the output as follows:

```
$ my-app | sed -r 's/.*\] - *//'
[21:06:51 DBG] Some message 111 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware>
[21:06:52 DBG] Some message 222 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics>
[21:06:52 ERR] Some message 223 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher>
[21:06:54 DBG] Some message 333 <s:PocApi.MyApp.Foo>
```

Now, **I wish to color code the output** (i.e., encode with ANSI color codes) so that:

1. The text inside and including `[` and `]` is always grey.
2. The message on lines which contain `<s:PocApi` are yellow.
3. The message on lines which contain `DBG` are light grey.
4. The message on lines which contain `ERR` are red.

*Note, the message is always between `]` and `<`.*

**Any ideas how I might do this?** Maybe `printf`, but I don't see a way to do pattern matching. Thanks for the help.

Oh, and for what it's worth, `my-app` is a long-running application that streams output.

Comment: what to do when you have 2 (or more) matches on a line (eg, all lines contain `DBG` while one of these lines contain `<s:PocApi`, and all lines also have `[....]`); is there a precendent on which color rule to use?

Comment: please update the question with a sample row with `ERR`

Comment: do you already have the sequences for the colors? if so, please update the question with the sequences

Comment: I updated with `ERR` and the rules to account for duplicate matching conditions. As for the color codes, it doesn't really matter. I just want to know how to apply a color, any color, to a pattern. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simulate the output from `my-app`:

```
$ cat input
[metadata] - [21:06:51 DBG] Some message 111 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware>
[metadata] - [21:06:52 DBG] Some message 222 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics>
[metadata] - [21:06:52 ERR] Some message 223 <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher>
[metadata] - [21:06:54 DBG] Some message 333 <s:PocApi.MyApp.Foo>
```

One `awk` idea:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "${line}"
    sleep 2
done < input |
awk '
BEGIN       {          # foreground colors    # background colors
              red    = "\033[1;31m"           # 41m
              green  = "\033[1;32m"           # 42m
              yellow = "\033[1;33m"           # 43m
              blue   = "\033[1;34m"           # 44m
              purple = "\033[1;35m"           # 45m
              reset  = "\033[0m"
            }

/DBG/       { msg_color=blue   }
/<s:PocApi/ { msg_color=yellow }
/ERR/       { msg_color=red    }

            { line=$0

              pos=index(line,"] - ")          # these 2 lines replace
              line=substr(line,pos+4)         # the current sed script

              pos=index(line,"]")
              out=green substr(line,1,pos) reset " " msg_color
              line=substr(line,pos+2)

              pos=index(line,"<")
              out=out substr(line,1,pos-2) reset substr(line,pos-1)
              print out
            }
'
```

This generates:

[image]

**NOTES:**

- assumes all lines start with `^[...] - [...]` followed at some point by a left arrow (`<`)
- the `while read ... do < input |` is to simulate OP's program output being piped to `awk` (ie, `my-app | awk ...`)
- OP hasn't provided rules for what happens when 2 (or more) rules apply to the same line (eg, line contains both `DBG` and `<s:PocApi`) so I've picked an arbitrary precedent (patterns matched later in script take precedence over patterns matched earlier in script)
- assumes there's a single space before/after all messages and said spaces are not to be colorized
- color codes were derived from this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code); OP should be able to find additional colors with a general web search on something like `ansi color codes`; also keep in mind available colors can vary based on the terminal (type)

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E "s/.[^[]*([^]]*ERR])([^<]*)/$(tput setaf 8)\1$(tput sgr 0)$(tput setaf 9)\2$(tput sgr 0)/;\
/DBG][^<]*<s:PocApi/s/.[^[]*([^]]*])([^<]*)/$(tput setaf 8)\1$(tput sgr 0)$(tput setaf 11)\2$(tput sgr 0)/;\
/<s:PocApi/ ! {s/.[^[]*([^]]*DBG])([^<]*)/$(tput setaf 8)\1$(tput sgr 0)$(tput setaf 7)\2$(tput sgr 0)/}" input_file
```

Comment: If you need to determine what arguments to add to `tput` you can check https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4055d6df5b6e4ea87c5a72dc2d604193

Comment: This returns an error: `sed: 1: "s/.[^[]*([^]]*ERR])([^< ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: @ChrisMiller Are you on a mac?

Comment: @markp-fuso GNU `sed` 4.7

Comment: Yes, I'm on macOS.

Comment: @ChrisMiller Then this slight change will work on MacOS `sed -Ee "s/.[^[]*([^]]*ERR])([^<]*)/$(tput setaf 8)\1$(tput sgr 0)$(tput setaf 9)\2$(tput sgr 0)/;\
/DBG][^<]*<s:PocApi/s/.[^[]*([^]]*])([^<]*)/$(tput setaf 8)\1$(tput sgr 0)$(tput setaf 11)\2$(tput sgr 0)/;\
/<s:PocApi/ ! {s/.[^[]*([^]]*DBG])([^<]*)/$(tput setaf 8)\1$(tput sgr 0)$(tput setaf 7)\2$(tput sgr 0)/" -e '}'`