# How to colorize output from bash command?

Tags: bash, colors, output, yt-dlp

I've seen many similar questions, but none really works for me.
I have a simple script that downloads latest 2 video episodes from one channel, so I can watch them later on mobile in offline mode.  It uses `yt-dlp` command with `-w` switch not to overwrite if video exists.  I would like to colorize "Destination" so I see more clearly file name, and "has already been downloaded" if file has already been downloaded.
So my script looks like this:

```
    cd /tmp
EPI=$(curl -s https://rumble.com/c/robbraxman | grep  -m 2 "href=/\v"| awk '{print $5}' |awk -F\> '{print $1}')
for i in ${EPI//href=/http://rumble.com}; do
  printf "\e[1;38;5;212m Downloading \e[1;38;5;196m $i\e[m \n"
  yt-dlp -f mp4-480p -w $i
done
```

output of the `yt-dlp` is like:

```
[Rumble] Extracting URL: http://rumble.com/v2820uk-let-me-show-you-brax.me-privacy-focused-app.html
[Rumble] v2820uk-let-me-show-you-brax.me-privacy-focused-app.html: Downloading webpage
[RumbleEmbed] Extracting URL: https://rumble.com/embed/v25g3g0
[RumbleEmbed] v25g3g0: Downloading JSON metadata
[info] v25g3g0: Downloading 1 format(s): mp4-480p
[download] Let Me Show You Brax.Me - Privacy Focused App [v25g3g0].mp4 has already been downloaded
[download] 100% of   20.00MiB



[Rumble] Extracting URL: http://rumble.com/v2820uk-let-me-show-you-brax.me-privacy-focused-app.html
[Rumble] v2820uk-let-me-show-you-brax.me-privacy-focused-app.html: Downloading webpage
[RumbleEmbed] Extracting URL: https://rumble.com/embed/v25g3g0
[RumbleEmbed] v25g3g0: Downloading JSON metadata
[info] v25g3g0: Downloading 1 format(s): mp4-480p
[download] Destination: Let Me Show You Brax.Me - Privacy Focused App [v25g3g0].mp4
[download]   3.8% of  525.67MiB at    5.79MiB/s ETA 01:27^C
```

So I would probably need to pipe output somehow, and then color it.  `yt-dlp` actually colors progress when downloading.  I've tried to put `grc` in front of `yt-dlp` but didn't color it.

Comment: I don't work with `yt-dlp` so I'm not sure if/how `yt-dlp's` colorization may interact with your desired colorization so fwiw .... [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74987715) may be of interest if the objective is to apply different colors to various strings in the output streaming from the `yt-dlp` call

Comment: to keep your code less complicated I'd probably wrap the coloeization code (eg, `awk` script from that linked answer) in a function and then have your feed the `yt-dlp` output to the function; ymmv ...

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso This use of awk is a bit much for my knowledge, also never really used functions in bash, but probably could learn to use it.  Can you propose at least aprox solution.  I just want to color filename or message that exists in red.  No other colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can colorize specific things you want using `grep`:

```
yt-dlp 'URL' | grep --color -P "^|(Destination.*|.*has already been downloaded)"
```

Basically it will match all lines with `^`, so those lines will still be printed, however since this match contains no visible characters those lines will not be colored.

Then you just add in the parts you want colored after the regex `|`. The `--color` shouldn't be neccesary, just adding it to make sure that is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Maximilian ... That works, and very simple/short.  It doesn't show % counting while downloading, but good enough.

Comment: @DenisZ You can show percent while downloading in title bar with `yt-dlp --console-title` or you can print as newline with `yt-dlp --newline`. Unforunately `grep` has issues with displaying progress bars natively so there is no perfect way.

Comment: Thanks @Maximilian, that's brilliant... btw how can I reset console title to `[screen #: user@host:/dir]`

Comment: Maybe the `-E` flag will work as well, no?

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes `-E` should would work as well.

Comment: btw @MaximilianBallard I was able to reset my console title with help of ChatGPT :)  so I added `printf "\033]0;\007"` to my script.  (it just removes last part where yt-dlp displays the status